# Where is this spacing coming from?

Tags: css, margin, padding

It's been a long day and I can't think what is causing the spacing between my divs

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a8zxuk7L/)

```
.sticker {
    position:relative;
    width:123px;
    height:68px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:8px;
    border:1px solid #777777;
}
```

I've tried all sorts with margin/padding but I can't seem to get all the divs to touch

Answer (score 0):

They're `display:inline-block`, so whitespace (including your linebreaks) is not discarded.